# How order array descending by date and time?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have array of objects:

```
[{id:'124',name:'ttt', MeasureDate:"2015-04-05T18:46:38"}, 
 {id:'589',name:'mmm', MeasureDate:"2015-05-05T18:46:38"}, 
 {id:'45',name:'yyy' , MeasureDate:"2016-01-05T18:46:38"},
 {id:'567',name:'eee', MeasureDate:"2016-05-05T18:46:38"}]
```

I neet to order array above descending by `date and time`:

```
[{id:'567',name:'eee', MeasureDate:"2016-05-05T18:46:38"},
 {id:'45',name:'yyy' , MeasureDate:"2016-01-05T18:46:38"},
 {id:'589',name:'mmm', MeasureDate:"2015-05-05T18:46:38"},
 {id:'124',name:'ttt', MeasureDate:"2015-04-05T18:46:38"}]
```

How can I implement it in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

```js
var data = [{id:'124',name:'ttt', MeasureDate:"2015-04-05T18:46:38"}, 
 {id:'589',name:'mmm', MeasureDate:"2015-05-05T18:46:38"}, 
 {id:'45',name:'yyy' , MeasureDate:"2016-01-05T18:46:38"},
 {id:'567',name:'eee', MeasureDate:"2016-05-05T18:46:38"}];
 
var sorted = data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return Date.parse(b.MeasureDate) - Date.parse(a.MeasureDate);
});

console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply sort it with sort and [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

This is possible, while the date is an [ISO6801](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and that is a sortable string.

```js
var array = [{id:'124',name:'ttt', MeasureDate:"2015-04-05T18:46:38"}, {id:'589',name:'mmm', MeasureDate:"2015-05-05T18:46:38"}, {id:'45',name:'yyy', MeasureDate:"2016-01-05T18:46:38"}, {id:'567',name:'eee', MeasureDate:"2016-05-05T18:46:38"}];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.MeasureDate.localeCompare(a.MeasureDate);
});

console.log(array);
```